# iPhone 5 table view contente issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, autolayout

I've a very strange problem with the following code.
On iPhone 5S, 6, and 6+ work perfectly. But on iPhone 5 create an extra space between nav bar and the table view.
If I remove the code inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews` On iPhone 5S, 6, and 6+ table view goes under nav bar, but on iPhone 5 the table frame is correct !

All iPhones have iOS 9

Ideas?

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken,^{
        self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.topLayoutGuide.length, 0, self.bottomLayoutGuide.length, 0);
        self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.topLayoutGuide.length, 0, self.bottomLayoutGuide.length, 0);
    });
}
```

Comment: What version of iOS is on the iPhone 5 and the other devices?

Comment: are you using a tableviewcontroller? can you maybe share your project?

Comment: No, I use a UITableView attached on UIViewController's view via Storyboard

Comment: could you maybe show a screenshot or something from the viewcontroller in your storyboard?

Comment: Make sure Extend edges under top bars is checked.